# The name myCustomer does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

I have an aspx page and a c# class. I am trying to display the property value of the data. It works with Eval, but does not work if I use the name of the class.property.

Can you explain the following issues I am having with this code:

1. I cannot use myCustomer.Name
2. The code never breaks at the itemdatabound function. The row value is always null.
3. The data displays on the screen twice.

   Name | Age | City 
       Name: Donna 
       Age:  40          Donna| 40  | New York
       City: New York

This the code for Customer.aspx file

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Customer.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Customer" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

     <asp:DataGrid id="testDataGrid" runat="server" OnItemDataBound = "testDataGrid_ItemDataBound" >

        <Columns><asp:TemplateColumn>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
            <tr><td>Name :</td><td><asp:TextBox   runat="server" ID="Name" Text= '<%# myCustomer.Name %>' visible="true"/> </td></tr>
            <tr><td>Age :</td><td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Age" Text= '<%# Eval("Age") %>' visible="true" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>City :</td><td><asp:TextBox  ID="City" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' visible="true" runat="server"/></td></tr>
           </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
         </Columns>         
    </asp:DataGrid>
    <asp:Button id="Add" text="Add customer" onclick="AddCustomer" runat="server"></asp:Button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code for Customer.aspx.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Customer : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
       List<myCustomer> customerList;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            customerList = new List<myCustomer>();

            myCustomer co1 = new myCustomer { Name = "Donna", Age = 40, City = "New York" };
            myCustomer co2 = new myCustomer("Raj", 10, "New York");
            myCustomer co3 = new myCustomer("Art", 16, "New York");
            customerList.Add(co1);
            customerList.Add(co2);
            customerList.Add(co3);
            testDataGrid.DataSource = customerList;
            testDataGrid.DataBind();
        }

        public void testDataGrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
        {
            DataRowView row = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
            if (row != null)
            {
                  int rowIndex = e.Item.DataSetIndex;
            //    TextBox tb1 = e.Item.FindControl("CustomerName") as TextBox;
            //    tb1.Text = customerList[rowIndex].Name;
            //    TextBox tb2 = e.Item.FindControl("Age") as TextBox;
            //    tb2.Text = customerList[rowIndex].Age.ToString();
            //    TextBox tb3 = e.Item.FindControl("City") as TextBox;
            //    tb3.Text = customerList[rowIndex].City;

            }
        }

        public void AddCustomer(Object sender,
                       EventArgs e)
        {
            // When the button is clicked,
            // change the button text, and disable it.
            myCustomer co4 = new myCustomer("tammy", 45, "New York");
            customerList.Add(co4);
            testDataGrid.DataSource = customerList;
            testDataGrid.DataBind();


        }
    }
}
```

The code for the class myCustomer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class myCustomer
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public String City { get; set; }

        public myCustomer()
        {
        }

        public myCustomer(string _name, int _age, string _city)           
        {
            Name = _name;
            Age = _age;
            City = _city;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to fix the data being displayed twice by adding AutoGenerateColumns="false" to the datagrid property.